# How to center the image inside of figure?

Tags: css, image, center, centering

I have tried everything to center an image on the page for @media only screen and (max-width:480px), however nothing will work.

The code is as follows:

**Front end**

```
<figure class="img1 embed">

<img src="Images/testimonial-2.jpg" alt=""/>

</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
/*** Base Caption Styles ***/
figure.embed,
figure.embed-top,
figure.overlay,
figure.embed-over {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
figure.embed img,
figure.embed-top img,
figure.overlay img,
figure.embed-over img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
figure.embed figcaption,
figure.embed-top figcaption,
figure.overlay figcaption,
figure.embed-over figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    /* neutral theme */
    color: rgba(50,50,50,1.0);
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.825);
}
```

Can anyone please advise what I would need to do to this code for the image to center? I've tried display: block; margin: 0 auto and margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto, but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You got float right in the first set of rules + your img is display block with width 100%

Comment: I know that, however, my question is how would I edit the code above to center the image using a media query 480px?

Comment: Are you having trouble with media query or centering an image? there are lot of questions about centering an image.  http://jsfiddle.net/64d71yjg/

Answer (score 4):

The element containing your image (the `figure`) is currently floated right.  Instead, place it within a container which is itself a block element.  Make the `figure` an inline-block element.  You can center the figure in its container by setting `text-align: center` on the outer container (be sure to set it back to `initial` so text within is not also centered).  In addition, you can center the image within by removing `width:100%` and adding `auto` `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

```css
.outer {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

/*** Base Caption Styles ***/
figure.embed,
figure.embed-top,
figure.overlay,
figure.embed-over {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: initial;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
figure.embed img,
figure.embed-top img,
figure.overlay img,
figure.embed-over img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
figure.embed figcaption,
figure.embed-top figcaption,
figure.overlay figcaption,
figure.embed-over figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    /* neutral theme */
    color: rgba(50,50,50,1.0);
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.825);
}

figcaption {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<figure class="img1 embed news">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250" alt="">
  <figcaption> Text. </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also make the `figure` display block and remove width 100%

Comment: This worked (thanks!), however, now the figcaption is no longer contained within the image (on other pages). It stretches across the width of the page. Any ideas on how to amend the css so it is contained within the image?

Front end:
    <figure class="img1 embed news">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250" alt="">
    <figcaption>
    Text.
    </figcaption>
    </figure>

Comment: Charlie, I had to update my example to take this additional element into account - in this example there is a new containing div - hopefully this is OK for your purposes.

Comment: @MatthewG 

Thanks for that. The problem I have now is when downsizing the browser to 360px, the image is not exactly centring on the <p> below:               '<div class="outer">
            
            <figure class="img1 embed news">
    <img src=http://placehold.it/250" alt="">
            
    <figcaption>
    Text.
    </figcaption>

   </figure>

            </div>'

            <p>Text.</p>

Comment: I am glad you found my answers helpful, if there are more details that are not represented in your question you may have to fill out more details or ask another question.  But glad it is working so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just style de image with "margin: auto;"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).