# I need to center images inside a gallery, nothing works

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment, center

I bought a wordpress theme named Photographer and I try to show the images centered inside the gallery.

I asked on their support forum, and they gave me this code

```
.gallery-item {  text-align: center; width: 100%; }
```

But that streches the portrait images to the width of the landscapes ones, thus making them really long.
I tried every single solution which I managed to find, it seems like impossible to do it.
I mention that even in the Wordpress page editor I aligned the images on center.

An example page here: http://vladilas.ro/test/portfolio/mihaela-si-paul-gura-humorului-rarau-2015/

If anyone has an idea on how to solve this, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the images to be, there are several images on that website

Comment: Those images are contained within a `figure` element which is positioned `absolute`. You horizontally center an absolutely positioned element by declaring `left` and `right` properties with values of `0`, while declaring a `margin` property with the value of `auto` (as you would with any `block` element). In the end, it means you will need to declare the following rules `right: 0;
    max-width: max-content;
    margin: auto;`, for the selector `.gallery-item`

Comment: It’s looks pretty good already, u will spoil it if u adjust width

Comment: i think this link might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325033/how-to-center-the-image-inside-of-figure

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

.gallery-item {margin: 0 auto;}

Answer (score 0):

add the following css.

```
figure {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: initial;
 vertical-align: top;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0.5em;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 background: white;
 overflow: hidden; 
}

figure.img {    
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then remove `.gallery-item {float: left; }`

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This should stop the stretching & position center:

`.gallery-item {margin: 0 auto; position:relative; float:none; max-width:100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Since your gallery items are absolutely positioned, you can add this rule to your custom CSS to center them horiontally:

```
.gallery-item {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked. This is really crazy.

A thing I did before posting the question here was to manually specify `margin-left` to a fixed value in pixels only for the portrait shots. But it was not the ideal solution, as some of my older photos are a little bit lower in resolution, so they would appear somewhere left to the center.

I managed to solve this problem with some luck, I think.
The CSS code is:

```
.gallery-icon.portrait
{
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

I'm aware that this might not be the best possible sollution, but for now it seems to work :)
Thanks a lot for your help, and maybe tell me what you think about my CSS :))